# Removing links from a PDF using iSharpText not all links removed

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, hyperlink, itext

From what I have found online and read in other questions similar, the way to remove links to not write them out in the annotations, basically replacing the annotations that contain links with an empty annotation. This works to some extent but does not remove all the links.

I seem to be able to write out all the links to a .txt file, but cannot remove them. Below is my code, I am just reading the .pdf in as bytes, and then writing back to file from the bytes returned, for testing purposes.

How would I go about removing or disabling all the hyperlinks, mailto links etc, even if the user accessing the PDF is using a PDF reader that has the 'Create Links from URLs' option set to true?

I am open to a solution that psychically removes the hyperlink altogether or just replaces it as an empty string, just so long as a user is not directed to the link if they click on it.

I am also open to using other PDF SDKs such as ActivePDFToolkit or Aspose PDF.

If vb.net is not your thing, I can convert this to C#.

```
  Public Function RemoveHyperLinks(bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
            Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(bytes)
            Try
                Dim pageCount As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
                For i As Integer = 1 To pageCount
                    Try
                        Dim pageDictionary As PdfDictionary = reader.GetPageN(i)
                        Dim annots As PdfArray = pageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS)
                        Dim newAnnots As New PdfArray()
                        If annots IsNot Nothing AndAlso annots.Length > 0 AndAlso annots.ArrayList.Count > 0 Then
                            If Not ContainsHyperLinks(annots) Then
                                reader.Dispose()
                                Return bytes
                            End If
                            For Each a As PdfObject In annots.ArrayList
                                Dim annotDict As PdfDictionary = CType(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(a), PdfDictionary)
                                If annotDict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not annotDict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK) Then
                                    newAnnots.Add(annotDict)
                                End If
                            Next
                            pageDictionary.Put(PdfName.ANNOTS, newAnnots)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Return bytes
                    End Try
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Using Doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document()
                    Using writer As New PdfCopy(Doc, ms)
                        Doc.Open()
                        Dim i As Integer = 1
                        While i <= reader.NumberOfPages
                            writer.AddPage(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i))
                            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
                        End While
                        Doc.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
                reader.Dispose()
                Return ms.ToArray()
            End Using
            Return bytes
        End Function

        Private Function ContainsHyperLinks(list As PdfArray) As Boolean
            Dim t As Boolean
            Try
                For Each a As PdfObject In list.ArrayList
                    Dim annotDict As PdfDictionary = CType(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(a), PdfDictionary)

                    If annotDict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK) OrElse annotDict.Get(PdfName.A) IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim annotAction As PdfDictionary = annotDict.GetAsDict(PdfName.A)
                        If annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI) Then
                            Dim uriLink As PdfString = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI)
                            If annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI) IsNot Nothing Then
                                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\links.txt", uriLink.ToString & " " & vbNewLine)
                                t = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        If annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URL) Then
                            Dim urlLink As PdfString = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URL)
                            If annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URL) IsNot Nothing Then
                                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\links.txt", urlLink.ToString & " " & vbNewLine)
                                t = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        If annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTOR) Then
                            Dim gotorLink As PdfString = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOR)
                            If annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOR) IsNot Nothing Then
                                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\links.txt", gotorLink.ToString & " " & vbNewLine)
                                t = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        If annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTOE) Then
                            Dim gotoeLink As PdfString = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOE)
                            If annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOE) IsNot Nothing Then
                                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\links.txt", gotoeLink.ToString & " " & vbNewLine)
                                t = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        If annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTO) Then
                            Dim gotoLink As PdfString = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTO)
                            If annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTO) IsNot Nothing Then
                                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\links.txt", gotoLink.ToString & " " & vbNewLine)
                                t = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        If annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT) Then
                            Dim js As PdfString = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT)
                            If annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT) IsNot Nothing Then
                                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\links.txt", js.ToString & " " & vbNewLine)
                                t = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                File.AppendAllText("C:\pdfTests\errors.txt", ex.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return t
    End Function
```

C#:

```
public byte[] RemoveHyperLinks(byte[] bytes)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
        try
        {
            int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    PdfDictionary pageDictionary = reader.GetPageN(i);
                    PdfArray annots = pageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
                    PdfArray newAnnots = new PdfArray();
                    if (annots != null && annots.Length > 0 && annots.ArrayList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (!ContainsHyperLinks(annots))
                        {
                            reader.Dispose();
                            return bytes;
                        }
                        foreach (PdfObject a in annots.ArrayList)
                        {
                            PdfDictionary annotDict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(a);
                            if (annotDict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE) != null && !annotDict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK))
                            {
                                newAnnots.Add(annotDict);
                            }
                        }
                        pageDictionary.Put(PdfName.ANNOTS, newAnnots);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return bytes;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(Doc, ms))
                {
                    Doc.Open();
                    int i = 1;
                    while (i <= reader.NumberOfPages)
                    {
                        writer.AddPage(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref i), i - 1);
                    }
                    Doc.Close();
                }
            }
            reader.Dispose();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    private bool ContainsHyperLinks(PdfArray list)
    {
        bool t = false;
        try
        {
            foreach (PdfObject a in list.ArrayList)
            {
                PdfDictionary annotDict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(a);

                if (annotDict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK) || annotDict.Get(PdfName.A) != null)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annotAction = annotDict.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
                    if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI))
                    {
                        PdfString uriLink = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI);
                        if (annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI) != null)
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\links.txt", uriLink.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                            t = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URL))
                    {
                        PdfString urlLink = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URL);
                        if (annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URL) != null)
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\links.txt", urlLink.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                            t = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTOR))
                    {
                        PdfString gotorLink = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOR);
                        if (annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOR) != null)
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\links.txt", gotorLink.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                            t = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTOE))
                    {
                        PdfString gotoeLink = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOE);
                        if (annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOE) != null)
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\links.txt", gotoeLink.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                            t = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTO))
                    {
                        PdfString gotoLink = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTO);
                        if (annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTO) != null)
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\links.txt", gotoLink.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                            t = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT))
                    {
                        PdfString js = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT);
                        if (annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT) != null)
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\links.txt", js.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                            t = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\pdfTests\\errors.txt", ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: How do you test that some links remain? Some pdf viewers automatically create links where they find URLs, probably you saw those...

Comment: @mkl You are correct, some if not most pdf viewer/editors will automatically create links from URLs/URIs. You can change the preferences and set the 'Create Links from URLs' option to true. I don't have control which pdf editors the users use, and if possible I want to remove the link all together, replace the URL with an empty string or something.

Comment: *"replace the URL with an empty string or something."* - editing pdf content can be fickle.

Comment: @mkl so what is the solution? If someone puts a link to a malicious web site in a PDF, I would not want a user to be able click on it, and be directed to said malicious site.

Comment: Well, itext has redaction capabilities, so you can redact away what you recognize as URLs. But probably some pdf viewers recognize different stuff as URLs. So you can never be 100% sure you remove all URLs and so prevent all auto-links. And you may also recognize text as URLs which isn't, and by redacting it away you remove regular content... so there is no *the solution*...

Comment: If text search or selection it's not necessary ... you alway can get the ratty way. Get a image of each sheet in order to dump into a new file. With ABCPdf it's easy for example.